# Plot decision boundary for text classification

Tags: scikit-learn, classification

I am looking for examples that show how to plot decision boundaries for text classification. I know about some of the examples in the sklearn documentation, but how do I apply them to text data?

I am not even sure, what to plot. Can a decision boundary be plotted for this?

I was thinking of using the result from the CountVectorizer somehow and then turning it into an np.array.

Are there any good examples online?

Comment: There's really not much of a difference between plotting decision boundaries for non-text classification problems. At the end of the day, those `sklearn` algorithms are using feature matrices (whether from `CountVectorizer` or a normal `numpy` array). Highly-dimensional text data will likely make this plotting difficult, however, so some form of SVD might be necessary.

Comment: but what do I use for the axes? The frequency of the words?

Comment: Think about [this](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/tree/plot_iris.html) example. How are the two vectors plotted on the axes related to the classification problem? To answer your question: you would have *many* axes in a text classification problem, because your feature matrix is so huge, so that's why SVD is important.

Comment: aaah right, okay, I think I got it. I was thinking about it wrongly. Now I just have to get SVD working ;) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The difficulty here is that text classification is a high-dimensional problem, where the dimensionality equals the size of the vocabulary. Plotting this in 2d would require the application of a dimensionality reduction technique first, e.g, pca or t-sne and then training the learning algorithm on this new representation. Even that way though, I doubt how informative your plot will be.

You could use a toy example, with only 2-3 words to visualize a line (2d) or a surface (3d) separating the classes, but it would be a toy example.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Are there any other types of plots that would make sens for text classification to visualize how the classifier worked? Or maybe some other types of plots?

Comment: You could use the classifiers decision boundary to find which are the words with the biggest weight for the classification problem. For example, in a sentiment classification problem (positive/negative) framed as a text classification one, you would expect words like "awesome/amazing/terrible" to have high weights.

Comment: A shameless plug: to check weights and visualize them in examples you can use [eli5](https://github.com/TeamHG-Memex/eli5) library. It is in pre-alpha; docs (currently very incomplete) for master branch: http://eli5.readthedocs.io/en/latest/overview.html#basic-usage

Comment: @geompalik Thanks for your idea!